# Convert Raw PNG data to base64 in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, png

I have an api that gives me raw png data as response, Want to convert the raw data to a file or a base64 string that can be invoked later. Below is the sample of the response that I get from the api. Can someone tell me on how this can be achieved

```
    �PNG


IHDR���(-sRGB���sBIT|d� IDATx���w|SU��'I��i��[(��7(�NDQ� �*����EPq�" ���""�Be�e�M�޻i����(���mҦM�����y�7�{����{���'��"A(A �����������d��h�^k����"���m"""""""���D.�X�P$tt{�������.kB�BNk'""""""r,�@�9t"""""""'��NDDDDDD�Љ�������:�`@'""""""r�DDD���f܊뮽���ha��s1~�dG7����)�8�DDD���? ���ᗭ?5��g�8�X�  ��'�ii)�hb�L�vn��.����4=/��zTV�c�>|����h�������g�8�1���Pb^{e9���p���N�GDDt1�:�YS&Omqn�k�������s�c��/���k>����V��՟���S'q㌙�w�C�޾�����,���!��v������   GЉ����T!6�'��c���   pqc��I�����������=��F��Z�F���X�~5�Z-�B#���k���޽�@QQ!�{�-\;m&�����|�i~��W�\.ǃ�b��Q����X��*�T�����s;�����
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fs Module

`let fs = require('fs')`

`let writer = fs.createWriteStream('xyz.png')`

`writer.write(<RAW data here>)`;

If you getting file directly in body then

`let writer = fs.createWriteStream('xyz.png');`

`let fl = res.body.pipe(writer);` (res is your response from api)

`fl.on('finish', () => {...Things to do})`